# Call a specific item out of all the user of a firebase realtime database in Kotlin

Tags: firebase, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database

I want to get the address from another user out of my database but i can't call it because I don't know how to get it, because I have to call it over the id. Do you know how to get a specific information from another user or like all users? Until now I can only get all the informations like so:

```
 mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("User")

mDatabase.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(object : ValueEventListener {
    override fun onDataChange(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {
        val data = snapshot.value as? Map<String, *>
        Log.e("User", data.toString())
        // data is a map of { uid to User }
val locoloco = snapshot.child("Adresse").value.toString()

        if(!locoloco.isEmpty()) {
            val adresseUser = snapshot.child("Adresse").value as? Map<String, *>?

            val wasauchimmer = snapshot.key
            val haha = snapshot.getValue()
            Log.e("Key",wasauchimmer.toString())

                    Log.e("Address", adresseUser.toString())

        }

    }

    override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Loading user data failed: \n" + error.message)
    }
})
```

and this is the database I'm referring to:

[image]

This is my outcome of the log I am getting right now:

```
2021-02-15 16:47:41.977 24358-24358/com.example.discoverme E/Address: null
2021-02-15 16:47:41.977 24358-24358/com.example.discoverme E/User: {q946wkGYXVRdYPLppv4j51cIQxp1={UserID=q946wkGYXVRdYPLppv4j51cIQxp1, Anwendertyp=Fotograf/Videograf, Name=buesra}, ZzmI1VsENEULsCX9NjSMtW064Mm1={UserID=ZzmI1VsENEULsCX9NjSMtW064Mm1, Email=eva.schumacher@gmail.de, Spezialisierung=[Familien, Architektur, Interior], Geburtstag=26.06.1999, Anwendertyp=Fotograf/Videograf, Telefon=022150055025, Stundenlohn=62€, Adresse=Zülpicher Str.386, Infotext=Hallo, ich heiße Eva und bin Fotografin., Name=Eva Schumacher}, NAzZGnwiAfaiEkEGRGyzRla0Cwo2={UserID=NAzZGnwiAfaiEkEGRGyzRla0Cwo2, Spezialisierung=[Architektur, Passfotos, Film], Anwendertyp=Fotograf/Videograf, Name=Frederik Löhmann}, bnc3GmwTS9RackTkbjOMd2H2pz72={UserID=bnc3GmwTS9RackTkbjOMd2H2pz72, Anwendertyp=Suchender, Name=Marion Ewert}}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To load the data for a specific user, you'll need to know the UID of that specific user. With that, you can then load their data with:

```
mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("User")

mDatabase.child("MAzZGnwiAfaiEkEGRGyzRla0Cwo2").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(object : ValueEventListener {
  ...
```

---

If you don't know the user's UID, all you can do is load all users and loop over them. That last part of missing in your current code, and looks like:

```
mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("User")

mDatabase.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(object : ValueEventListener {
    override fun onDataChange(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {
        for (userSnapshot in snapshot.children) {
            val data = userSnapshot.value as? Map<String, *>
            Log.d("User", data.toString())
            ...
        }
    }

    override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Loading user data failed: \n" + error.message)
    }
})
```

Also see the Firebase documentation on [listening for value events](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/lists-of-data#kotlin+ktx_2).

Comment: I tried the second one with the loop, but I only get null as a value. Like this:

Comment: 2021-02-15 22:08:29.294 18611-18611/com.example.discoverme E/Hey: null
2021-02-15 22:08:29.294 18611-18611/com.example.discoverme E/Hey: null
2021-02-15 22:08:29.294 18611-18611/com.example.discoverme E/Hey: null
2021-02-15 22:08:29.294 18611-18611/com.example.discoverme E/Hey: null
2021-02-15 22:08:29.294 18611-18611/com.example.discoverme E/Hey: null
2021-02-15 22:08:29.294 18611-18611/com.example.discoverme E/Hey: null
2021-02-15 22:08:29.294 18611-18611/com.example.discoverme E/Hey: null

Comment: Okay, I solved it, but now the loop is running through my data three times and I can't explain myself why. Also every time I add an if clause in my loop where I check a value or if the value is not null it tells me that this is always true, which can't be because some values of address are for sure null.